# How to query CardDAV

Tags: carddav, sabredav

I was expecting to find much more information on CardDAV on the web, but unfortunatly I just don't get it.

The [rfc6352](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352) states in [1-1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352#section-1) that a server must understand and make Address data server side searchable, but I don't know how to do it.

Could anybody give me a hint on ressources, on how to find out what I can send how to the server?
For starters I would like to:

- Connect with a user/paasword (Auth basic) to a CardDAV server
- Get the Addressbooks the user has access to and their hirarchy position
- For each address book get its entries (reduced to first/last name, numbers + types)

What I'm planning to do is build a gateway for Grandstream phones, which is accessable via https and returns a generated phonebook XML.

Might be usefull to add, that I want to run against kopano/sabre-dav.

Comment: This one is pretty good: https://sabre.io/dav/building-a-carddav-client/

Comment: I mean, the RFC even comes with an example on how to query a server? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6352#section-8.6.2